# Amplify doesn't recognise pre-existing Vue.js project with Amplify

Tags: amazon-web-services, vue.js, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

I'm picking up development started by another team on a Vue.js app with AWS Amplify. They used Amplify Cli to add Auth to the app.

I've pulled the project down from GitHub. When I run the app, the Auth service is working fine.

I'm now trying to add Storage with `amplify add storage`, but am struggling to get the Amplify Cli (which I've had working fine on my own projects) to work with the new project.

I've tried:

- `amplify configure project`, which fails with the message 'You are not working inside a valid Amplify project. Use 'amplify init' in the root of your app directory to initialize your project, or 'amplify pull' to pull down an existing project.' (but I don't want to init a new project, this is an existing project that I've git pulled)
- `amplify pull --appId myAppIDFromTheAmplifyConsole --envName dev`, which fails with the message 'File at path: '/[thefullpath]/amplify/.config/local-env-info.json' does not exist' (and I can see that that file doesn't exist. The other team have confirmed that the file has never existed.)

My questions are:

1. Should I run `amplify init` as the first bullet point error message suggests? The auth service is working and I don't want to break the existing cognito user pools that Amplify created. Will `amplify init` push or rerun the cloudformation scripts and therefore change the backend?
2. If I shouldn't, what should I do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question without an answer, so I'll answer for future visitors.
You need to run `amplify init` after `amplify configure`, it will initialize a project and associate your local project with a cloud environment.  `amplify init` will ask questions and after answering them, `/[thefullpath]/amplify/.config/local-env-info.json` file will be created.
`local-env-info.json` should be in `.gitignore` file, because it contains information about the locally initialized environment.

Note: `amplify init` will not push your changes to the cloud

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure you have the Amplify CLI installed, amplify version checking: amplify --version
2. On the project folder run: amplify pull --appId [your app id] --envName [environment name]
3. After you run the above command it will ask: aws region, select the region where your amplify project uploaded, next--> enter AWS access key and AWS secret key
   once amplify pull is a success, you are done, now you can add more service you want.